# How to call javascript function of asp.net user control

Tags: asp.net

i hv designed one user control, and used on my aspx pages whereever needed.
my user control does not have  tag.
now i want to call some javascript function onload of this user control.
can anyone tell me how to achieve....... ?

any help appreciated

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just type the script directly in the body of your .ascx file, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        initialize();
    }

    window.onunload = function() {
        GUnload();
    }
</script>
```